# add words from file java

Tags: java, parsing, text-files

I have a txt file which contains only this one line "website which allows me to do". I want to build a tree based on the file such that: root is the "+" sign, first letter of a word in the file is the child of the root PROVIDED that letter already doesn't exist in the tree. Here is my code:

```
public class TreeTest {
    
    public void parse(File f) throws Exception {
        Node root = new  Node('+'); //create a root node
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] words = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");
            
            for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                addToTree(words[i], root);
            }
        }//end of while
                
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(root.children()));
        
        br.close();
    }
    
    public void addToTree(String s, Node root){
    
            char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
            
            if(characters.length > 0){
                Node addChar1 = new Node(characters[0]);
                
            
                //if the root has no children ??
                //add the first addChar1 as a child
                if (root.hasChildren()==false){
                    root.addChild(addChar1);
                    
                }
                //root has children
            
                //get the child nodes of the root
                Node[] rootChildren = root.children();
                
                for(int i=0; i<rootChildren.length; i++){
                    Node rootChild = rootChildren[i];
                    //see if the addChar1 already exists in the tree
                    //if it doesn't
                    
                    if(!rootChild.equals(addChar1)){
                        //add the addChar1 as a child of the root
                        root.addChild(addChar1);
                                                     
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(addChar1.getItem() + " Exists in the tree already");
                    }           
                
                }
                
            }//end of addToTree
            
    }
    
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         TreeTest test = new TreeTest();
         
         File f = new File("textFile.txt");
         test.parse(f);
     }
}
```

I don't understand why the output is:

```
 character   w    Exists in the tree already
 character   w    Exists in the tree already
[w, a, m, m, t, t, t, t, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d]
```

why does it only outputs that 'w' exists in the tree even though there are order letters as well such as 'o' ? I have overriden the equals method and the hashCode

Comment: This does not solve anything but you can change this:
for(int i=0; i<rootChildren.length; i++){
                    Node rootChild = rootChildren[i];

to
for(Note rootChild : rootChildren){

it will then loop through all the rootChildren.

Comment: Why was the question changed and was the answer I gave to the previous question unaccepted? :|

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing it to one of the children.

```
for(int i=0; i<rootChildren.length; i++){
                    Node rootChild = rootChildren[i];
                    //see if the addChar1 already exists in the tree
                    //if it doesn't

                    if(!rootChild.equals(addChar1)){
                        //add the addChar1 as a child of the root
                        root.addChild(addChar1);

                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(addChar1.getItem() + " Exists in the tree already");
                    }
```

Already adds it after it isn't equal to the first child. You want to see if it equals ANY of the children. What you could do is something like this:

```
  int equalsnrofchildren = 0;
    for(Node rootChild : rootChildren){//loops through all the children
                        //see if the addChar1 already exists in the tree
                        //if it doesn't

                        if(rootChild.equals(addChar1)){
                            equalsnrofchildren++;

                        }
    }

    if(equalsnrofchildren == 0){
    root.addChild(addChar1);
    }else{
System.out.println("already exists..");
}
```